# Button to clear MySQL table of data

Tags: php, mysql, database, button

I'm creating a program that uses a form to adds records to a database called "Tasks" for display. The table inside the DB is called "ID" with the columns "ID", "Name" and "Hours". However, I also want a button that clears the table of records but leaves the layout of the table intact. I am completely new to PHP so forgive any major mistakes.

I think the button in HTML is created like this:

```
<h2>Delete All Tasks</h2>
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
```

And I think the PHP to clear the table is like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Tasks");

mysql_query ("DELETE FROM ID");
};
```

Is this correct? I have another form before this to input tasks. How would I  link the PHP to the button only so when I click the button it clears the database.

Additionally, I've explored some ways to delete only a specific row using a user inputted form to specify the row's id, but the problem is the id for each row in MySQL is not based on how many entries there are, but on how many total entries you've entered, even if data has been previously deleted. e.g the id would go like 1, 2, 3, 15 meaning there have been 15 rows ever placed even if rows 4-14 have been deleted. I don't want to have to show the user each row's id for them to identify which row to delete. Is there a way there a way to delete a row if the user only specifies the name column?

Comment: if your method in HTML is `post` then use $_POST super global not $_GET.Also you cant use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE it will be faster

Comment: Also, use `mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM ID")` - `mysql_*` is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and you shouldn't intermix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Change in **Delete.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Tasks");
    mysql_query ("TRUNCATE TABLE ID"); 
}
```

Know About [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)
For deleting according to name

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    mysqli_select_db ($conn, "Tasks");
    mysql_query ("DELETE FROM ID WHERE name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."'"); 
}
```

Know About [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html)